# In java regex how to capture forward slash followed by .(dot)

Tags: java, regex

In java I am using regex `\.([a-zA-Z0-9]{0,}\/.[a-zA-Z0-9])|([a-zA-Z0-9]{0,}\/.[a-zA-Z0-9])` this will capture forward slash followed by dot.

Ex:
Case1:

```
REGEX: \.([a-zA-Z0-9]{0,}\/.[a-zA-Z0-9])|([a-zA-Z0-9]{0,}\/.[a-zA-Z0-9])
INPUT: input.data.test/.1234
RESULT : It is capturing till test/.1 but I want to capture till test/.1234
```

Case2:

```
REGEX: \.([a-zA-Z0-9]{0,}\/.[a-zA-Z0-9])|([a-zA-Z0-9]{0,}\/.[a-zA-Z0-9])
INPUT: input.data.test/.1234.cap
RESULT : It is capturing till test/.1 but I want to capture till test/.1234
```

But the regex that I am trying with is not working.How to get the above result.The regex is correct or not?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\.([a-zA-Z0-9]{0,}\/.[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,})
```

https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output

but in fact, it could be some problems in real code with **{0,}** construction

[image]